# Merging multiple Git branches and pushing them to the remote server (Gitlab)

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, pull-request

I am new to Git (Gitlab) branching and merging, and right out of the box, of course, have a fairly complex scenario.

A repo ("`myapp`") has a feature branch called "`cleanup`". I was asked to branch *that* branch locally, add some changes, merge those changes with `cleanup`, then merge `cleanup` with the mainline ("`origin`" ?). So I cloned `myapp`, switched to the `cleanup` branch, and then branched it and called that branch `mycleanups`:

```
origin/mainline (exists on remote Gitlab server as well as locally)
    +---> cleanup (exists on remote Gitlab server as well as locally)
          +---> mycleanups (just exists locally)
```

So now what I want to do is:

1. Merge `mycleanups` with `cleanup`, hopefully only locally
2. Then push that merge (`mycleanups`+`cleanup`) to the `cleanup` branch (**unless this step is unnecessary**)
3. Merge `cleanup` with `origin` and push those changes. This *should* require some kind of "**Merge Request**" on Gitlab (from `cleanup` to `origin`)...

   I'm comfortable merging, but not sure what I should strictly do locally vs. what should be pushed to the remote Gitlab server. Can someone provide a set of concrete steps (with sample `git` commands!) of how I could achieve this multi-branch merge, both locally and remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `mycleanup` branch was unnecessary.

You've got your clone, so you'd checkout the `cleanup` branch (which creates a local copy of the remote branch `cleanup`):

`git checkout cleanup`

Make some changes. Commit them.

At this point, your local branch is ahead of the remote branch. You can see this information with `git status`.

Following this, run `git push`. If no one else pushed in the interim, it will accept it. Otherwise, it will reject it and you'd need to bring in the changes from the remote (a merge - git pull).

When doing the checkout of cleanup it will set it to track the remote branch of the same name. This is for future pulls and pushes - so it knows where to push to and pull from.

Following this, in Gitlab, it should show you the most recently pushed branch in the Merge Requests page. You can then hit "New Merge Request" and it will submit it for the project's owner to review and merge into `mainline` at their leisure.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation @bcmcfc (+1) - a quick followup for you though. You say "*Make some changes. Commit them and push them.*" But then you say "*At this point, you local branch is ahead of the remote branch.*" **This is where my mental hangup is!** If I *just* pushed the changes to the remote Gitlab server (`git push`), then why would my local branch be *ahead* of the remote branch...shouldn't they now be exactly the same (since I just pushed them)?!?! Thanks for any clarity here!

Comment: You've not pushed yet at that stage - you've only checked out the remote and made some changes.

Comment: Sorry, not trying to be difficult here (seriously!). Your verbatim statement is: "*Make some changes. Commit them and push them. (git commit, git push)(At this point, your local branch is ahead of the remote branch.*" So you are saying: (1) make changes, (2) commit, (3) push, and then (4) local branch is ahead of remote branch. Am I reading this right?!?

Comment: My bad, I may not have read your comment right. Your summary is correct, yes!

Comment: So if I've just pushed the changes to the remote server, how am I (locally) ahead of that remove server?

Comment: Edited for clarity - apologies

Comment: No worries at all - sorry if I was being a PITA! Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, **last** followup question (I promise!) - once I submit the new Merge Request, what is the process for mainline merge? Does the project owner merge locally or on Gitlab somehow (in the UI)? I ask because I am the project owner on some repos and I may have to service a Merge Request myself!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100681/discussion-between-bcmcfc-and-smeeb).

Answer (score 1):

Perform:

> git checkout cleanup
>
> git merge mycleanup
>
> git pull origin cleanup
>
> git push origin cleanup

Comment: Thanks @yorammi (+1) - can you explain each of these steps though (teach a man to fish vs show a man to fish, etc.)? For instance I'd like to resolve merge conflicts inside of [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com), how might I set this up? Also, where would the Merge Request on Gitlab come into play? Thanks again!!!

Comment: The main difference between Git and other source control systems - as I see it - is that a Git user should understand better what is happening behind the scenes. There are many great sites where you can learn this. Start with https://git-scm.com/.
In general, the above commands do exactly what you described in words but with Git commands: merge, pull and push.